# Install SharePoint 2010 SP1 before or after running configuration wizard

Tags: installation

Completely new standalone installation of SharePoint 2010. I'm currently at the "Run the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard" checkbox.

Should I a) install the SP1 before configuration or b) configure the system and then install SP1? Or does it not matter.

Typically, on a server, I would install all the service packs before starting configuration - so you have the latest versions from the start.

Not sure if the same applies to SharePoint whereby the configuration wizard could install additional features which then need upgrading with the service pack.

Answer (score 3):

After installing SP1, you need to install the latest Cumulative Update (CU), which is currently the Aug 2011 CU. After running that CU you'll need to re-run the SharePoint Product config wizard again after that is installed.

If I was doing a fresh install, I would install and configure SP2010, and run the config wizard to make sure it all came up as expected and worked. and then I would install SP1, and the Aug CU and then re-run the config wizard.  I am not certain if you can skip the PS Config wizard after the initial installation of 2010.

Comment: I based my comment about CU's after SP1 on the Microsoft KB article [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2460045) where it says:

"After you install SharePoint Foundation 2010 SP1 or SharePoint Server 2010 SP1, you must also install the corresponding June 2011 Cumulative Update refresh package". As the other post below points out, you could try it without if you didn't need the items in the latest CU.

Comment: Mostly in my answer I was just trying to clear up the confusion should anyone dig further, everyone will have an opinion about how to install SharePoint, and in my opinion they all have valid points. Also the August 2011 hotfix is ideal now over the June 2011 fix as it includes the June 2011 fixes.

Answer (score 0):

The verdict is still unclear as to whether or not the latest CU is needed for SharePoint 2010, you'll hear arguments on both sides with some saying "stop at SP1 and go no further" and some saying "go on to the latest CU", I've seen farms configured both ways with no issues.  You don't need to run the config wizard until all components are installed if you're doing a first-time install.  My suggestion is to do it this way:

1. Look up how to "SlipStream" the service pack 1 install into SharePoint 2010, and do so, this way you can install both at the same time

   After installing, run config wizard and start your farm

   (Optional depending on your point of view) install the latest CU

   Run the config wizard again

Comment: Thanks - I've gone with installing base product and then SP1 (which is what you're suggesting with #1 in a way) and then configured the farm. Didn't even know there was a further set of hotfixes. Neither did I know there was yet another stackxxx site for SharePoint itself!